# Store JQuery result into var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done my searches and tried in different ways but i don't understand why my problem persist.

I want to store the number of links inside a div into a javascript variable.

If i do this, it works:

```
alert ($("#uploaded-files a").length); // i can see the alert with the right value (5)
```

Then I tried to store the previous result into a javascript variable:

```
var mynumber = $("#uploaded-files a").length;
alert (mynumber)  // i can see the alert but the value is 0 and not 5
```

I also tried this one

```
var mynumber = $(("#uploaded-files a").length).val();  
alert(mynumber ); // i don't even see the alert message box
```

Comment: If the first one works, the second one will work; the third code sample will result in an error you'd see in the developer console. (Actually maybe it wouldn't be an error; it wouldn't be correct however.)

Comment: You need to make sure your script runs after the document has loaded. The `alert` forced that; the other options allow calculation before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of document ready block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Try your code here and it should work like a charm.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to wait for JS to get all your selector elements from the DOM

```
$(function(){ // DOM is now ready
   /* all your code here */
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the document is not ready to select elements when you code is executed.

You have a race condition problem. Use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mynumber = $("#uploaded-files a").length;
    alert (mynumber);
});
```

I'm sure it will work.